# openssl ignores Serial number extension

Tags: openssl, x509

Good day! 
I created a certificate request with such result :

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIICszCCAZsCAQAwKzEKMAgGA1UEChMBczEQMA4GA1UECxMHb3JnVW5pdDELMAkG
A1UEAxMCY24wggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQC4p/WHGkLZ
DGuUenb8e+FtwimfPQvAGJU4IwVKgjjk3cqqdED2PgyeSKQEehyWdnEaGaKdDQ72
unsPfOeRYAbzhEeKNM0qH/jx5gC5CO0/lq58UQOtBg4GXMLCMel+QIofBb1UGbLo
KviHLR02jfqYrUf72GY83JrhUGlzAJEl6upDvuZalp5qXql9ge8ylfGx/iOUYPk7
/gvfTOLDQmDKcUQ9nW8H9U+cl82lcsBMv7V4XCoG16GfEIziLyFHtLwvAwvGE2md
IEnoMwhY0cUxp/c8bzL0hvNvMDy1lNBJ14wohdTh95/Guf46d8DtWc7e1Nrb+biT
HxWsftA4WEQdAgMBAAGgQzBBBgkqhkiG9w0BCQ4xNDAyMDAGA1UEBQQpVURJRDow
MDAwMDAwMC03YTBlLTkyNTUtZmZmZi1mZmZmYmY4ZmYyZDUwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
BQADggEBAEm8HXmmxZ7B6Omcezuhle1Xz/9Iiaet2SnkSwm0dVmZXzyamWFHSls+
1biMtZb3Ath0TeDQ7kUh40SyFBKOTSWD8EhbgsMrys0ALUOJ16r2mGXbVdnoc/52
dm8jKXSqB/tKa4AXDQJkR6GNJtNu3k4XHSz25felkZosqGHdPmnQGiPDpJsFenxm
yD+nYTUrzrMM4FrBKLDex4mT0raFEkxN52wIwQ+UtI84OfxebztKSr+WCeafCKnV
idQrTBcM5zMdAPSgKIdh2kFOr3WdXgLonQiQ8GVleBdFGy0aw1LRVZ3+XsIrnEx2
L1dRm4u70iXtUwYw5tSaK6KNT7SJo00=
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

in two words - it says :

```
cn
Certificate request

Public Key Info
Key Algorithm:  RSA
Key Parameters: 05 00
Key Size:   2048
Key SHA1 Fingerprint:   E4 .. E9 49 A3 D3

Public Key: 30 82 01 0A 02 82 01 01 ... 03 01 00 01
```

Now the most important :

```
Extension
Identifier: Serial Number
Value:  55 44 49 44 3A 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 2D 37 61 30 65 2D 39 32     35 35 2D 66 66 66 66 2D 66 66 66 66 62 66 38 66 66 32 64 35
Critical:   No
```

I want THIS Extension serial number to be in my future certificate.
But when I do something like

```
openssl x509 -req -in ../req.req -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out user.crt -days 5000 -extensions v3_usr -CAcreateserial
```

I don't get my extension in result user.cer. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that there are several issues.

First of all, your extension value is incorrectly formed. It misses nested ASN.1 type identifier for `extnValue` field. According to [RFC5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280), X.509 Extension is:

```
Extension  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
     extnID      OBJECT IDENTIFIER,
     critical    BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
     extnValue   OCTET STRING
                 -- contains the DER encoding of an ASN.1 value
                 -- corresponding to the extension type identified
                 -- by extnID
     }
```

Under `extnValue` (which is OCTET_STRING) you should put nested type (I don't know exact syntax for Serial Number extension). It can be SEQUENCE, another OCTET_STRING, or INTEGER (since serial numbers are integers).

However, your nested type is missing:
[image]
there should be another nested node under selected OCTET_STRING, while, you placed serial number directly as `extnValue` payload.

If this extension is intended to instruct CA to place specified serial number in the certificate (as a FIELD), then you violate another requirement:

> [**§4.1.2.2**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.2)

> Certificate users MUST be able to handle serialNumber values
> up to 20 octets.  Conforming CAs MUST NOT use serialNumber values
> longer than 20 octets.

Your serial number looks like is a bit longer than 20 octets. In addition, you may violate first part of this section:

> It MUST be unique for each certificate issued by a given CA (i.e., the
> issuer name and serial number identify a unique certificate).

That is, if user asks for specific serial number, it may lead to serial number non-uniqueness.

**Edit:**
According to Ilya Matveychikov, nested type shall be **PrintableString**. This means that your extension value should be:

```
13 2B 55 44 49 44 3A 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 2D
37 61 30 65 2D 39 32 35  35 2D 66 66 66 66 2D 66
66 66 66 62 66 38 66 66  32 64 35
```

when encoded, it will look as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In accordance with [OID 2.5.4.5](http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/2.5.4.5.html) definition, there must be `PrintableString` placed onto the `extnValue`:

```
serialNumber ATTRIBUTE ::= {
    WITH SYNTAX PrintableString (SIZE (1..ub-serialNumber))
    EQUALITY MATCHING RULE caseIgnoreMatch
    SUBSTRINGS MATCHING RULE caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch
    ID id-at-serialNumber
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the `-CAcreateserial` option. It is documented as:

> -CAcreateserial
>
> with this option the CA serial number file is created if it does not exist: it will contain the serial number "02" and the certificate being signed will have the 1 as its serial number. If the -CA option is specified and the serial number file does not exist a random number is generated; this is the recommended practice.

For explicitly setting a serial number, you might want to utilize the option `-CAserial` instead:

> -CAserial filename
>
> sets the CA serial number file to use.
>
> When the -CA option is used to sign a certificate it uses a serial number specified in a file. This file consist of one line containing an even number of hex digits with the serial number to use. After each use the serial number is incremented and written out to the file again.
>
> The default filename consists of the CA certificate file base name with ".srl" appended. For example if the CA certificate file is called "mycacert.pem" it expects to find a serial number file called "mycacert.srl".

Simply write the desired serial number into a file and use it.